# VUE- computed function for updating variables

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-visualization

I try to dive deep into computed functionality of VUE.

I understand that computed runs only when the value tied into the function changes.

So I was expecting the computed function I wrote would work well.
However, it runs only when the function is in 'method' hook.

Why Can I not make that happen when it is in computed?

my code is as below.

-html-

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>


<div id="exercise">
    <!-- 1) Show an alert when the Button gets clicked -->
    <div>
        <button @click='showalert'>Show Alert</button>
    </div>
    <!-- 2) Listen to the "keydown" event and store the value in a data property (hint: event.target.value gives you the value) -->
    <div>
        <input type="text" v-on:keyup='updatekey'>
        <p>{{ value }}</p>
    </div>
    <!-- 3) Adjust the example from 2) to only fire if the "key down" is the ENTER key -->
    <div>
        <input type="text">
        <p>{{ value }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script src='./app.js'></script>
```

app.js

```
new Vue({
        el: '#exercise',
        data: {
            value: ''
        },
        methods:{
            showalert(){
                alert('You just clicked')
            },

        },
        computed:{
            updatekey(e){
                this.value=event.target.value
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in browser console after using this code?

Comment: computed are getters/setters - in your case updatekey is undefined, to use the setter it should be something like `@onEvent="updatekey=$event"`, dont use it like a method

Comment: Since you're only setting the value, the computed prop is better off being used as a method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because, `computed` contains the `properties`, something which returns a value, rather than an even handler.
Event handler are closures which should be captured inside the `methods`.

Have a look at sample example from Vue.js docs:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello'
  },
  computed: {
    // a computed getter
    reversedMessage: function () {
      // `this` points to the vm instance
      return this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="example">
  <p>Original message: "{{ message }}"</p>
  <p>Computed reversed message: "{{ reversedMessage }}"</p>
</div>
```

Here, `reversedMessage` is used just like a normal `data` property in your DOM, but is infact tied to other data properties.

while in your case, `updatekey` is clearly a handler, which needs to make some changes or do some computations when an event is triggered.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Super clear. especially your saying "computed contains the properties, something which returns a value, rather than an even handler." made me understand the logic super clearly. So Can I see 'computed' as something RETURNS a value which, eventually is to be used like DATA??

Comment: Exactly! They should be used that way. They are derived data properties